# Youtube embeded code

Tags: youtube, embedded-video

I would like to get the image thumbnail of the video's which we get from the from youtube videos embedded code. 
Can any one help me????

Answer (score 0):

Use oEmbed protocol instead of pure embed code! It will give you more information including url to thumbnail ;)

For example: 
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DM3r2XDceM6A&format=json

You can find out more about oEmbed @ http://www.oembed.com/